# How To Run "attachedfunction" Attribute While VBA Web Crawling

Tags: vba, jsp, internet-explorer, automation, web-crawler

We're trying to VBA web crawl an internal website, and everything was been going fine, until we go to click on one label in particular.

We are able to target the label, and click it without a problem. This causes a popup to appear, and the screen loads additional data. When clicking manually, the information appears normally. However, when we click using VBA, the popup seems like it's attached to the VBA. The popup will appear, and the data loads, but VBA stops processing, but the moment we close the popup, VBA resumes. The code is not erroring - it's pausing the code.

We believe the website interacts with VBA, because we do not have to write code making IE wait for the page load; the next line of the code executes the moment each screen loads.

Here is the code in the DOM for the label:

```
<LABEL tabIndex=24 id=ID class=inputHref style="POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 5px; Z-INDEX: 200; TOP: 15px" attachedfunction="somefunction" defaultValue="undefined">Label Title</LABEL>
```

We believe the "attachedfunction" function is running something behind the scenes that is halting VBA. Is there any way we can maneuver around this? Any insights would be helpful!

Thank you.

EDIT 1:

Here is the VBA code in a class to click on the label

```
Sub RepoSecureLink()
    Set Me.htmlDoc = Me.Window.document.frames(1).document.frames(1).document.frames("iframeMain").document
    Set Element = Me.htmlDoc.getElementById("ID")
    Me.Element.Click ' Hard Stop - Popup Window
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you use vba to close the pop-up? What type of pop-up are we talking about? Is this a window.alert or something else? Do you manually have to dismiss currently?

Comment: Please see the post - it has been edited to include the Sub to click the label

Comment: We cannot use VBA to close the popup. Once the screen opens, this is where VBA freezes - like it's waiting on code to execute.
It is not a window alert, it is a true pop-up window housing more information.
We are able to dismiss it manually - once we dismiss it, we have control over VBA again from the same line item - no error.

Comment: With a DoEvents can you not grab the handle of the pop-up and close?

Comment: We are able to grab the HWND on a separate test case, but we want to scrape the data in this window first.

Comment: We have tried "With Events" but the same issue occurs in the crawler: once we kick it off, VBA halts.

Comment: Do you mean DoEvents?

Comment: No, but we tried DoEvents as well and encountered the same problem

Comment: Just added mouse controls to the program, and telling my mouse to click on the label works, but this is something I'd like to avoid if possible.